# Can a usercontrol be bound and set by different viewmodels in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, custom-controls

Don't know if this can be done--or where to look (so here I am :) ).

I have  a usercontrol, EditorView, that is implemented in the XAML like:

```
<v:EditorView   Grid.Row="3"
   DataContext="{Binding Editor}"
   FontSize="100" 
   FontWeight="Bold" />
```

Now the usercontrol, EditorView, receives these values by:

```
 <SimpleTextBlock 
   Background="#FFE24848"
   FontSize="{Binding     FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
   FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"   
   />
```

Once in the custom control, SimpleTextBlock, I would like the customcontrol to send its values for FontSize, FontWeight, etc. out to the viewmodel of the usercontrol for use in some calculations. (I might add, I need the values from the custom control after it is implemented by the XAML to obtain the actual values it was created with).

So the questions are:

1. Can and how is this done?
2. How to perform the calculations only after the UserControl has been instantiated?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SimpleTextBlock is a custom control, just add one or two additional dependency properties to it, called, say DataBoundFontSize and DataBoundFontWeight. Then override OnApplyTemplate, on which execution the values for FontSize and FontWeight should already be set and set their values to DataBoundFontSize and DataBoundFontWeight. For safety, and in case FontSize and FontWeight change later, you should also subscribe to changes in those properties and keep the others synchronized.

Last, apply the bindings to your view model:

```
<SimpleTextBlock 
   Background="#FFE24848"
   FontSize="{Binding     FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
   FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"   
   DataBoundFontSize="{Binding Path=FontSizeOnViewModel}"
   DataBoundFontWeight="{Binding Path=FontWeightOnViewModel}"
   />
```

If this was not a custom control I would create a custom action/behavior that monitors the properties you are interested in and then sends the values to the view model through data bindings using dependency properties as well.

Now, just out of curiosity, I believe that FontSize and FontWeight are automatically inherited to controls contained within the visual tree, so did you try and see if the FontSize and FontWeight are inherited to your custom control without the binding? If that was the case then you would not need all these complexity and you could just bind to the view model from there.

Comment: SimpleTextBlock inherits from  TextBlock, but I seem to need the RelativeSource... to get the values from the UserControl that contains the SimpleTextBlock. Can you provide a link or help on OnApplyTemplate and/or creating a custom behavior? Much thanks.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I am using Windows 7, VS2010, .net 4.0 --- if it matters :)

Comment: It appears that OnApplyTemplate would work perfectly, if I could get how to use it in a usercontrol...I quess I'll spawn this to another question. Thanks.

Comment: After further study, it is apparent that my use of inheriting from a textblock is entirely messed up--need to inherit from control.

Comment: Inheriting from TextBlock can indeed be problematic, but not impossible, take a look at one implementation here http://polaris.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Polaris.Client.Controls.Wpf/Controls/WatermarkTextBox.cs and right next to that one, another one for an entirely custom text block control inheriting from Control instead http://polaris.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Polaris.Client.Controls.Wpf/Controls/FormattedTextBlock.cs